# C++/cli operator= overload reference

Tags: c++, .net, operator-overloading, c++-cli

I've got a problem to overload operator= in c++/cli :

```
public ref class wString
{
public:
    wString(int length)
    {
        this->Bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(length);
        this->Length = length;
    }
    Byte% operator[](int index)
    {
        return this->Bytes[index];
    }
    wString^ operator+(wString^ wstr)
    {
        wString^ res = gcnew wString(this->Length + wstr->Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < this->Length; i++)
            res[i] = this->Bytes[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < wstr->Length; i++)
            res[i + this->Length] = wstr[i];

        return res;
    }
    void operator=(String^ str)
    {
        array<Byte>::Resize(this->Bytes, str->Length);
        this->Length = str->Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < str->Length; i++)
            this->Bytes[i] = str[i];
    }

    void operator=(wString^ wstr)
    {
        array<Byte>::Resize(this->Bytes, wstr->Length);
        this->Length = wstr->Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < wstr->Length; i++)
            this->Bytes[i] = wstr[i];
    }

    void operator=(const char *str)
    {
        int length = sizeof(str);

        array<Byte>::Resize(this->Bytes, length);
        this->Length = length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            this->Bytes[i] = str[i];
    }

public:
    int Length;
private:
    array<Byte>^ Bytes;
};

MyForm(void)
{
    wString^ test1 = gcnew wString();
    wString^ test2 = gcnew wString();
    wString^ test3 = gcnew wString();
    String^ test4;

    test4 = "123";  // no error because test4 is a native type String

    test1 = "123";  // error
    *test2 = test4; // works well call operator= overload
    test2->operator=("123");    // works well call operator= overload

    test3 = test1 + test2;  // doesn't work, don't know what appens here
    test2[0] = 4;   // works well
```

So, my question is :
How can I declare the operator= overload to use it like this : test2 = "123"; ?

And how does the builtin String class to be able to allocate a String like that : String^ foo = "123"; ?

Comment: wString% operator=(String^ str).  And Array::Resize().  Don't ignore the C4244 warning.  System::String is *heavily* micro-optimized in the CLR, you can never get close.  Don't do this.

Comment: I don't understand how I can use marshal_as to implement a String of unsigned char ? Maybe you can give me an exemple ?

Comment: Thanks Hans, but I need to manage unsigned chars buffers on my project, and unfortunatly, String class only manage chars between 0 and 127. So, I don't see any other solution...

Comment: test2 = test4 with wString% operator=(String^ str) doesn't compile...

Answer (score 0):

@Dan You're right, The error was in the serial port bytes conversion :

```
res = String::Concat(res, System::Text::Encoding::Unicode->GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes));
```

I've replaced `Text::Encoding::ASCII` by `Text::Encoding::Unicode`
It works fine.